# Chroot user exit jail

Tags: security, chroot, openssh

I am using OpenSSH chrootdirectory feature to give access to a user via `ssh`.

Can this user exit the jail and return to the normal OS environment? Maybe with `su`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user does not have root access (or any way to gain it, such as exploiting an insecure setuid program), escaping a chroot jail should be impossible.

With root access, escaping a chroot jail is trivial. In fact, the `chroot(2)` manpage even gives instructions:

> This call does not change the current working directory, so that  after
>   the call '.' can be outside the tree rooted at '/'.  In particular, the
>   superuser can escape from a "chroot jail" by doing:
>
> ```
>    mkdir foo; chroot foo; cd ..
> ```

Answer (score 2):

No it cannot, it would give them an error. That's the whole point of chroot. They'll be only locked up in a location without being able to go out that location.
But if you want tias.